# Hey everyone! Newbie here. How can I get started making my own DE just like the people on r/unixporn

Tags: desktop-environments, .desktop, i3-wm

So basically i somehow found my way into the subreddit `r/unixporn` where people share their truly amazing Desktop environments. Of course I immediatley want to make my own too, since I am full of cool ideas!
But I really do not know how to get started.

**However my current skills are good in C and shell script which might be useful for this task!**

Help would be very much appreciated. ***With that being said, I wish you guys a wonderful day!***

Comment: Maybe start by looking here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001892/how-to-create-a-simple-desktop-environment  Honestly, there isn't a straight forward one type of answer on how to do it.  You just gotta look around and find what you want.  Look into all the different types of desktop environments that are already out there like GNOME, Xfce4, LXDE, i3, Cinnamon, KDE Plasma, etc.  I do not recommend having more than one Desktop Environment on your system at a time because one can conflict with the other causing damage that can't be easily fixed.

Comment: Are they making their own DEs or just making themes for their chosen DE? There's a world of difference between the two. The last time I checked that sub, they were just using themes they'd found, created, or modified.

Comment: @KGIII both. Some make their own and some just add themes.

Comment: Okay. With that info, I have [this](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/desktop-environment-with-openbox-window-manager/) in my "To Do" notes, except I never got there to do it. It's still on my to-do list. That may be of interest to you.